# AddMessageFilter without Windows Forms?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'd like to use the functionality of System.Windows.Forms.Application.AddMessageFilter but my target application does not use Windows Forms. This functionality adds a filter to monitor Windows messages as they are routed. If anyone knows how this works, I wouldn't mind  writing my own code to perform the same function.

SetWindowLong with GWL_WNDPROC only affects received messages and I'd like to affect sent messages. System.Windows.Forms.Application is static but calling AddMessageFilter with an IMessageFilter that throws an exception does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a message hook to achieve what you want. In fact, a message hook is far more powerful than IMessageFilter because there are other kinds of hooks other than just windows messages sent to a window handle. For example you can hook system-wide keypresses or mouse movements.

See this article for more information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx